Why are these exceptions being thrown when I try to run the pad4pi demo scripts?
This is for the 3x4 membrane on a raspberry pi 4b.
Membrane link:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00NAY2XUS?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
I am using the pad4pi library to do all the backend gpio stuff for me, but I have not had a single working attempt after two full days. I have tried to use the demo included in the git clone from pad4pi:
#!/usr/bin/python

from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
import time

def print_key(key):
    print(key)

try:
    factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()
    keypad = factory.create_4_by_3_keypad() # makes assumptions about keypad layout and GPIO pin numbers

    keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(print_key)

    print("Press buttons on your keypad. Ctrl+C to exit.")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Goodbye")
finally:
    keypad.cleanup()

I expected a window to popup and read in input from the matrix, but instead I got these errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/rpigpiodemo.py", line 11, in <module>
    keypad = factory.create_4_by_3_keypad() # makes assumptions about keypad layout and GPIO pin numbers
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/pad4pi/rpi_gpio.py", line 44, in create_4_by_3_keypad
    return self.create_keypad(KEYPAD, ROW_PINS, COL_PINS)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/pad4pi/rpi_gpio.py", line 30, in create_keypad
    return Keypad(keypad, row_pins, col_pins, key_delay, repeat, repeat_delay, repeat_rate, gpio_mode)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/pad4pi/rpi_gpio.py", line 88, in __init
    self._setRowsAsInput()
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/pad4pi/rpi_gpio.py", line 128, in _setRowsAsInput
    GPIO.add_event_detect(self._row_pins[i], GPIO.FALLING, callback=self._onKeyPress, bouncetime=DEFAULT_DEBOUNCE_TIME)
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/younis/dev/matrixKeypad/pad4pi/rpi_gpio_demo.py", line 21, in <module>
    keypad.cleanup()
    ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'keypad' is not defined


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue


Have you wired the keypad to your RPi?  Do you know which GPIO pins you used?  create_4_by_3_keypad assumes a default set of GPIO pins.  Have you checked the code to make sure you used the same ones?

Yes I have! I thought it would be that but it wasn't

You need to figure out which pin is the problem.  Add print statements into pad4pi so you can see which pin you're working on.

so you're sure it's one of the pins acting up? I will triple check then
